# Find value over multiple columns and rows and be given the cell address

Tags: google-sheets, find

I’ve got a sheets with multiple data (date, no. ID, type, and %) over different columns and rows from a1 to yt:100. On another sheet, I’ve managed to list on a single column all the no. Ids and now I want a formula that finds these values all over sheet 1 and either:
-give me the cell address, so I can recuperate the other data by pulling values from cells next to it
-directly give  me the values of the columns next to the found value

I’m going crazy over it, do you think it’s even possible? Thanks!

I’ve tried VLOOKUP, INDEXMATCH, FILTER.. no joy

Comment: What is next to it? Offset by 1 column, or offset by -1 columns?

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?, it checks the whole range, and if it says "no", it stacks the ADDRESS of that CELL:

```
=REDUCE("List",A:C,LAMBDA(a,v,IF(v="no",VSTACK(a,CELL("address",v)),a)))
```

[image]